# Include audio from FFmpeg overlay in output

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm using the following command to combine two video files together, overlaying the second one at a certain point in the first file. The result is what I want except the audio from the overlayed file is missing.

`ffmpeg.exe -y -hide_banner -ss 00:00:00.067 -i promo.mov -i tag.mov -filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS+6.5/TB[a];[0:v][a]overlay=enable=gte(t\,6.5)[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a -map 1:a -c:v mpeg2video -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -af loudnorm=I=-20:print_format=summary -preset ultrafast -q:v 0 -t 10 complete.mxf`

Without the `-map 0:a` I get no audio at all, but the second `-map 1:a` does not pass the audio from `-i tag.mov`

I have also tried `amix` but that combines audio from both clips starting at the beginning, and I want the audio from the second file to begin when that file starts overlaying.

It would also be helpful if I could make the audio from the first clip drop lower at the time of the overlay.

Answer (score 1):

amix doesn't support introducing an input mid-way, so the workaround is to add leading silence. You can use the adelay filter to do this.

*make the audio from the first clip drop lower at the time of the overlay*

This is possible using a sidechaincompressor which takes two inputs and lowers the volume of the first input based on the volume of the second input.

So use,

`ffmpeg.exe -y -hide_banner -ss 00:00:00.067 -i promo.mov -i tag.mov -filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS+6.5/TB[1v];[0:v][1v]overlay=enable=gte(t\,6.5)[vout];[1:a]adelay=6.5s,apad,asplit=2[1amix][1aref];[0:a][1aref]sidechaincompress[0asc];[0asc][1amix]amix=inputs=2:duration=first[aout]" -map [vout] -map [aout] -c:v mpeg2video -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -af loudnorm=I=-20:print_format=summary -preset ultrafast -q:v 0 -t 10 complete.mxf`

Comment: This is still mixing the two together at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: I got it to work. Had to change the adelay to ```adelay=6500|6500``` to account for both channels of audio. Thank you for your help @gyan.

Comment: You're using an older version of ffmpeg.